# Deal With images same as Maps In Javascripts

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

is there any tool to help me work with an image in the same way i can deal with map, the task is to create a tool that will allow the user to upload a building layout and then set on it points that referring to row data.
i achieved that with Canvas but I'm not feeling it's completed or perfect
Because for example implementing zooming and dragging will make me lose a lot of things like mouse hover on the provide points or the x, y once it's zoomed is different from the actual image (Without zooming)

so any one now like these tool

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Is there any ready tool will let me work with images as map